# How to track external code in git

Tags: git

I'm working on a project where some code is original to the project, some code is modified from external sources (some of which use VCS like p4), and some code is mirrored from external sources.

How can I track the changes to the external code sources, while keeping my code intact?

Could I create a separate branch for each external source, and whenever they update it, check in their changes to that branch, then three-way merge that into the mainline?

Answer (score 1):

Does each external source need to be merged in to the main project, or can they be kept cleanly separated as libraries/modules/plugins?

#### Submodules

If they're libraries that you want to modify and track in git, you can use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). This lets you keep a project within a project, and makes it easy to update from that project source while making any changes of your own.

#### Rebasing

If it makes more sense to merge them into the main project, take a look at [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing). With a merge, your commit history can start to look really confusing, especially if you're pulling from multiple sources.

With rebasing, you basically stick one set of commits after another set, making it like everything was coded linearly one-after-the-other.

[Here's an article](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/) I found really helpful when learning `git rebase`.

Comment: I think rebase does what I'd want it to, but (this may be a somewhat stupid question:) does it require that you check in the original unmodified source code before changing it? (e.g. check in original, make changes, original gets updated, rebase to updated original?)

Comment: That's actually a really important question. You want to rebase your local commits _before_ you push to a remote repository. Rebasing is basically rewriting the commit history. Because of this, you don't want to rebase a remote repository that someone else may be using. They'll have a local copy and the next time they sync up with the remote, it can cause a lot of problems if the remote's commit history has changed (and no longer matches up with their local version). So it's okay to rebase as long as no one else has seen those commits yet.

Comment: And what's the proper way to do that if people have seen the commits?  Say the workflow that happens is I check in original, make changes, commit changes, push changes to server, other people pull those changes, commit and push back to server, I pull those changes, and now original gets updated?

Comment: Different teams use different workflows and I'm afraid there's no one true answer. To keep things simple, I'd say only rebase commits that haven't been pushed to a remote server yet. Once others have seen the commits, rebasing can cause problems if you aren't really careful.

Comment: So would a hackish (but functional) solution be to clone to another temp folder, do rebase merge, once everything is up to date, replace any files in the main repo with the updated version, then commit those changes just as a normal commit?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your setup. Would you be able to draw a diagram showing the different repos, sources, etc?